# C++ Digit Counting Weird Error

Tags: c++, while-loop

I have a very weird error. I have a very simple digit counting function. The function is going in an infinite loop if I do this:

```
int numOfDigits(int num, int count)
{
    while(num != 0) {
        count++;
        numOfDigits(num/10, count);
    }
    return count;
}
```

But it works this way:

```
int numOfDigits(int num, int count)
{
    while(num != 0) {
        count++;
        num /=10;
        numOfDigits(num, count);
    }
    return count;
}
```

I tried using gdb but couldn't figure out. I'm compiling with g++ on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Why are you calling `numOfDigits()` inside `numOfDigits()` when you don't even use the returned value? Use loop or recursion, not both.

Answer (score 4):

```
while(num != 0) {
  count++;
  numOfDigits(num/10, count);
}
```

This while-loop never terminates, because num is never actually modified. Thus it will never exit the loop if the condition wasn't false in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

```
int numOfDigits(int num, int& count)
{
    if(num != 0) {
        count=1+numOfDigits(num/10, count);
    }
    return count;
}
```

I have changed `count` as being passed by reference though it is not really required.  You have the `while` loop that goes on infinitely because `num` is not modified in that context.  You are mixing iteration and recursion.

Comment: Thanks. I was mixing recursion and iteration. Can you point me to a good reference for understanding recursion?

Comment: Pretty much any good book on Algorithms should have a section.

Answer (score 0):

Recursive functions require two things:

1. A terminating condition
2. A reducing clause

In your first example, you had the terminating condition `num != 0`...but not the reducing clause as @WorldSEnder pointed out (`num` was totally unaffected).

Also, there's no rule against iteration in recursion...but it usually makes things more complicated than it should be.